# How to write into a file without overriding the current content while limiting the file size in Java

Tags: java, append, overriding, bufferedwriter

Im using this code in order to write some text to a file, while limiting the size of the file to 1G

but every time a new text is entered, its overriding the current file content.
How do I disable the overriding and still keeping the file size limit?

```
public synchronized void writeToAFile(String msg,String filePath) {
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
    final long SIZE_1GB = 1073741824L;
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new LimitedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path), SIZE_1GB), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        writer.append(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Something went wrong while writing to the  file {} ", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the `LimitedOutputStream` is imported from ?

Comment: import org.xnio.streams.LimitedOutputStream;

Answer (score 0):

You should create appendable stream when defining `Files.newOutputStream(path)`.

So providing `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` option will be fix your problem

```java
// append to an existing file, fail if the file does not exist
// out = Files.newOutputStream(path, APPEND);

Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
```

To keep the file at the same size, you need to calculate how much room left in the file and open `LimitedOutputStream` accordingly.

```java
public synchronized void writeToAFile(String msg, String filePath) {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);

        final long fileLength = path.toFile().length();
        final long SIZE_1GB = 1073741824L;

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new LimitedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND), SIZE_1GB - fileLength), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            writer.append(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Something went wrong while writing to the  file {} ", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```